# Multi-citations with an at sign - Pandoc

Tags: bibliographies, citing, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

So I'm editing a document that is being converted to PDF with `pandoc`. It uses

```
@someAuthor
```

in the body to do citations.

`\cite` does not appear to work, rendering `??` in the document produced.

The document uses a `.csl` file to define the bibliography style.

Single citations appear as [1]

My question is:
how do I cite multiple sources, producing [1, 2, 3], as I would if `\cite{a, b, c}` worked?

Comment: `@` is certainly not the normal `biblatex` way to cite. You mention CSL files, so you can't be using `biblatex`. Are you using pandoc?

Comment: I literally just debugged this; yes it was a Pandoc issue/problem. Should I edit / answer or delete to record the discovery for future users?

Comment: By all means answer your own question if you found the solution. But please also edit your question to make it more useful: I.e. mention that you are using Pandoc, don't mention `biblatex`. Tag your question correctly. Use code highlighting etc. Technically your question might be off topic, but it might help other people as there is no pandoc.SX.

Comment: Hope that improves things appropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@references` are part of `pandoc`, not latex. `pandoc` uses semi-colons to separate references. Thus

```
[@someAuthor1; @someAuthor2]
```

Will render as

[1, 2]

given the appropriate `.csl` (eg bibliography style). Note that the square brackets are not produced twice in the document.